# Ubuntu on an Asus Transformer Prime?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

Can Ubuntu be put on a tablet that currently has Android on it (instead of android)?

I have a tablet (Asus Transformer Prime) that I would like to play with tech-wise and I wanted to know if there is a way I can get Ubuntu on it, so that I could use it with ROS to do robot design/programming.

Answer (score 0):

With an unlocked Prime it is possible to 'dual-boot' with Ubuntu.

The instructions are too extensive to go into here but you can google it and find many sites with instructions and also some videos on how to do it. The Prime is a nice piece of hardware.

Here are a few links to get you started:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1603921

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QB9u6OKgop4

http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-tf101-development/1467-dual-booting-transformer-pad-other-linux.html